# Dapr sidecar not injected after node recreate

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, amazon-eks, dapr

I currently use Dapr for my project which has multiple services. I've deployed it to AWS EKS.

But when the Kube node recreates, some service does not have a sidecar injected and shows **1/1 running** containers.

The sidecar will inject if I manually delete the pod and let it recreates.

Does anyone have this issue before? I've tried to get the log but the daprd sidecar never exists so there is no log, my API log is nothing related to dapr and the dapr-sidecar-injector does not show any failure.

I just think may when the kube node recreate the api pod created before dapr running so the annonation dapr.io does not work.

Comment: We are having the same exact issue. Deployment is fine, but if a pod is restarted the Dapr container isn't always injected.

Comment: @phat Did you fix this issue? I'm also facing the same issue